# C# Mono - Encoding supported

Tags: c#, character-encoding, mono

I'm trying to write a small program in Console, in windows it works great, but when I run it in Ubuntu over Mono project, I've problem with accented characters even if I'm in the good Encoding (iso-8859-1, UTF8, Unicode)

```
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(File.Open(@"C:\Temp\data.txt", FileMode.CreateNew), Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));
tw.WriteLine("éèçàôûêâ");
tw.Close();
```

So what're encoding supported in Mono for C# ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me on OS-X (mono-4.2.1) and Ubuntu 14.04 (mono 4.2.1):

[image]

[image]

Encoding wise, if you are looking at coreclr, then:

```
ENC ("ANSI_X3.4-1968", 20127 ),
ENC ("ANSI_X3.4-1986", 20127 ),
ENC ("ascii", 20127 ),
ENC ("cp367", 20127 ),
ENC ("cp819", 28591 ),
ENC ("csASCII", 20127 ),
ENC ("csISOLatin1", 28591 ),
ENC ("csUnicode11UTF7", 65000 ),
ENC ("IBM367", 20127 ),
ENC ("ibm819", 28591 ),
ENC ("ISO-10646-UCS-2", 1200 ),
ENC ("iso-8859-1", 28591 ),
ENC ("iso-ir-100", 28591 ),
ENC ("iso-ir-6", 20127 ),
ENC ("ISO646-US", 20127 ),
ENC ("iso8859-1", 28591 ),
ENC ("ISO_646.irv:1991", 20127 ),
ENC ("iso_8859-1", 28591 ),
ENC ("iso_8859-1:1987", 28591 ),
ENC ("l1", 28591 ),
ENC ("latin1", 28591 ),
ENC ("ucs-2", 1200 ),
ENC ("unicode", 1200), 
ENC ("unicode-1-1-utf-7", 65000 ),
ENC ("unicode-1-1-utf-8", 65001 ),
ENC ("unicode-2-0-utf-7", 65000 ),
ENC ("unicode-2-0-utf-8", 65001 ),
ENC ("unicodeFFFE", 1201),
ENC ("us", 20127 ),
ENC ("us-ascii", 20127 ),
ENC ("utf-16", 1200 ),
ENC ("UTF-16BE", 1201), 
ENC ("UTF-16LE", 1200),        
ENC ("utf-32", 12000 ),
ENC ("UTF-32BE", 12001 ),
ENC ("UTF-32LE", 12000 ),
ENC ("utf-7", 65000 ),
ENC ("utf-8", 65001 ),
ENC ("x-unicode-1-1-utf-7", 65000 ),
ENC ("x-unicode-1-1-utf-8", 65001 ),
ENC ("x-unicode-2-0-utf-7", 65000 ),
ENC ("x-unicode-2-0-utf-8", 65001 )
```

Otherwise:

```
ENC ("437", 437), 
ENC ("ANSI_X3.4-1968", 20127), 
ENC ("ANSI_X3.4-1986", 20127), 
// ENC (L"_autodetect", 50932), 
// ENC (L"_autodetect_all", 50001), 
// ENC (L"_autodetect_kr", 50949), 
ENC ("arabic", 28596), 
ENC ("ascii", 20127), 
ENC ("ASMO-708", 708), 
ENC ("Big5", 950), 
ENC ("Big5-HKSCS", 950), 
ENC ("CCSID00858", 858), 
ENC ("CCSID00924", 20924), 
ENC ("CCSID01140", 1140), 
ENC ("CCSID01141", 1141), 
ENC ("CCSID01142", 1142), 
ENC ("CCSID01143", 1143), 
ENC ("CCSID01144", 1144), 
ENC ("CCSID01145", 1145), 
ENC ("CCSID01146", 1146), 
ENC ("CCSID01147", 1147), 
ENC ("CCSID01148", 1148), 
ENC ("CCSID01149", 1149), 
ENC ("chinese", 936), 
ENC ("cn-big5", 950), 
ENC ("CN-GB", 936), 
ENC ("CP00858", 858), 
ENC ("CP00924", 20924), 
ENC ("CP01140", 1140), 
ENC ("CP01141", 1141), 
ENC ("CP01142", 1142), 
ENC ("CP01143", 1143), 
ENC ("CP01144", 1144), 
ENC ("CP01145", 1145), 
ENC ("CP01146", 1146), 
ENC ("CP01147", 1147), 
ENC ("CP01148", 1148), 
ENC ("CP01149", 1149), 
ENC ("cp037", 37), 
ENC ("cp1025", 21025), 
ENC ("CP1026", 1026), 
ENC ("cp1256", 1256), 
ENC ("CP273", 20273), 
ENC ("CP278", 20278), 
ENC ("CP280", 20280), 
ENC ("CP284", 20284), 
ENC ("CP285", 20285), 
ENC ("cp290", 20290), 
ENC ("cp297", 20297), 
ENC ("cp367", 20127), 
ENC ("cp420", 20420), 
ENC ("cp423", 20423), 
ENC ("cp424", 20424), 
ENC ("cp437", 437), 
ENC ("CP500", 500), 
ENC ("cp50227", 50227), 
    //ENC (L"cp50229", 50229), 
ENC ("cp819", 28591), 
ENC ("cp850", 850), 
ENC ("cp852", 852), 
ENC ("cp855", 855), 
ENC ("cp857", 857), 
ENC ("cp858", 858), 
ENC ("cp860", 860), 
ENC ("cp861", 861), 
ENC ("cp862", 862), 
ENC ("cp863", 863), 
ENC ("cp864", 864), 
ENC ("cp865", 865), 
ENC ("cp866", 866), 
ENC ("cp869", 869), 
ENC ("CP870", 870), 
ENC ("CP871", 20871), 
ENC ("cp875", 875), 
ENC ("cp880", 20880), 
ENC ("CP905", 20905), 
//ENC (L"cp930", 50930), 
//ENC (L"cp933", 50933), 
//ENC (L"cp935", 50935), 
//ENC (L"cp937", 50937), 
//ENC (L"cp939", 50939), 
ENC ("csASCII", 20127), 
ENC ("csbig5", 950), 
ENC ("csEUCKR", 51949), 
ENC ("csEUCPkdFmtJapanese", 51932), 
ENC ("csGB2312", 936), 
ENC ("csGB231280", 936), 
ENC ("csIBM037", 37), 
ENC ("csIBM1026", 1026), 
ENC ("csIBM273", 20273), 
ENC ("csIBM277", 20277), 
ENC ("csIBM278", 20278), 
ENC ("csIBM280", 20280), 
ENC ("csIBM284", 20284), 
ENC ("csIBM285", 20285), 
ENC ("csIBM290", 20290), 
ENC ("csIBM297", 20297), 
ENC ("csIBM420", 20420), 
ENC ("csIBM423", 20423), 
ENC ("csIBM424", 20424), 
ENC ("csIBM500", 500), 
ENC ("csIBM870", 870), 
ENC ("csIBM871", 20871), 
ENC ("csIBM880", 20880), 
ENC ("csIBM905", 20905), 
ENC ("csIBMThai", 20838), 
ENC ("csISO2022JP", 50221), 
ENC ("csISO2022KR", 50225), 
ENC ("csISO58GB231280", 936), 
ENC ("csISOLatin1", 28591), 
ENC ("csISOLatin2", 28592), 
ENC ("csISOLatin3", 28593), 
ENC ("csISOLatin4", 28594), 
ENC ("csISOLatin5", 28599), 
ENC ("csISOLatin9", 28605), 
ENC ("csISOLatinArabic", 28596), 
ENC ("csISOLatinCyrillic", 28595), 
ENC ("csISOLatinGreek", 28597), 
ENC ("csISOLatinHebrew", 28598), 
ENC ("csKOI8R", 20866), 
ENC ("csKSC56011987", 949), 
ENC ("csPC8CodePage437", 437), 
ENC ("csShiftJIS", 932), 
ENC ("csUnicode11UTF7", 65000), 
ENC ("csWindows31J", 932), 
ENC ("cyrillic", 28595), 
ENC ("DIN_66003", 20106), 
ENC ("DOS-720", 720), 
ENC ("DOS-862", 862), 
ENC ("DOS-874", 874), 
ENC ("ebcdic-cp-ar1", 20420), 
ENC ("ebcdic-cp-be", 500), 
ENC ("ebcdic-cp-ca", 37), 
ENC ("ebcdic-cp-ch", 500), 
ENC ("EBCDIC-CP-DK", 20277), 
ENC ("ebcdic-cp-es", 20284), 
ENC ("ebcdic-cp-fi", 20278), 
ENC ("ebcdic-cp-fr", 20297), 
ENC ("ebcdic-cp-gb", 20285), 
ENC ("ebcdic-cp-gr", 20423), 
ENC ("ebcdic-cp-he", 20424), 
ENC ("ebcdic-cp-is", 20871), 
ENC ("ebcdic-cp-it", 20280), 
ENC ("ebcdic-cp-nl", 37), 
ENC ("EBCDIC-CP-NO", 20277), 
ENC ("ebcdic-cp-roece", 870), 
ENC ("ebcdic-cp-se", 20278), 
ENC ("ebcdic-cp-tr", 20905), 
ENC ("ebcdic-cp-us", 37), 
ENC ("ebcdic-cp-wt", 37), 
ENC ("ebcdic-cp-yu", 870), 
ENC ("EBCDIC-Cyrillic", 20880), 
ENC ("ebcdic-de-273+euro", 1141), 
ENC ("ebcdic-dk-277+euro", 1142), 
ENC ("ebcdic-es-284+euro", 1145), 
ENC ("ebcdic-fi-278+euro", 1143), 
ENC ("ebcdic-fr-297+euro", 1147), 
ENC ("ebcdic-gb-285+euro", 1146), 
ENC ("ebcdic-international-500+euro", 1148), 
ENC ("ebcdic-is-871+euro", 1149), 
ENC ("ebcdic-it-280+euro", 1144), 
ENC ("EBCDIC-JP-kana", 20290), 
ENC ("ebcdic-Latin9--euro", 20924), 
ENC ("ebcdic-no-277+euro", 1142), 
ENC ("ebcdic-se-278+euro", 1143), 
ENC ("ebcdic-us-37+euro", 1140), 
ENC ("ECMA-114", 28596), 
ENC ("ECMA-118", 28597), 
ENC ("ELOT_928", 28597), 
ENC ("euc-cn", 51936), 
ENC ("euc-jp", 51932), 
ENC ("euc-kr", 51949), 
ENC ("Extended_UNIX_Code_Packed_Format_for_Japanese", 51932), 
ENC ("GB18030", 54936), 
ENC ("GB2312", 936), 
ENC ("GB2312-80", 936), 
ENC ("GB231280", 936), 
ENC ("GBK", 936), 
ENC ("GB_2312-80", 936), 
ENC ("German", 20106), 
ENC ("greek", 28597), 
ENC ("greek8", 28597), 
ENC ("hebrew", 28598), 
ENC ("hz-gb-2312", 52936), 
ENC ("IBM-Thai", 20838), 
ENC ("IBM00858", 858), 
ENC ("IBM00924", 20924), 
ENC ("IBM01047", 1047), 
ENC ("IBM01140", 1140), 
ENC ("IBM01141", 1141), 
ENC ("IBM01142", 1142), 
ENC ("IBM01143", 1143), 
ENC ("IBM01144", 1144), 
ENC ("IBM01145", 1145), 
ENC ("IBM01146", 1146), 
ENC ("IBM01147", 1147), 
ENC ("IBM01148", 1148), 
ENC ("IBM01149", 1149), 
ENC ("IBM037", 37), 
ENC ("IBM1026", 1026), 
ENC ("IBM273", 20273), 
ENC ("IBM277", 20277), 
ENC ("IBM278", 20278), 
ENC ("IBM280", 20280), 
ENC ("IBM284", 20284), 
ENC ("IBM285", 20285), 
ENC ("IBM290", 20290), 
ENC ("IBM297", 20297), 
ENC ("IBM367", 20127), 
ENC ("IBM420", 20420), 
ENC ("IBM423", 20423), 
ENC ("IBM424", 20424), 
ENC ("IBM437", 437), 
ENC ("IBM500", 500), 
ENC ("ibm737", 737), 
ENC ("ibm775", 775), 
ENC ("ibm819", 28591), 
ENC ("IBM850", 850), 
ENC ("IBM852", 852), 
ENC ("IBM855", 855), 
ENC ("IBM857", 857), 
ENC ("IBM860", 860), 
ENC ("IBM861", 861), 
ENC ("IBM862", 862), 
ENC ("IBM863", 863), 
ENC ("IBM864", 864), 
ENC ("IBM865", 865), 
ENC ("IBM866", 866), 
ENC ("IBM869", 869), 
ENC ("IBM870", 870), 
ENC ("IBM871", 20871), 
ENC ("IBM880", 20880), 
ENC ("IBM905", 20905), 
ENC ("irv", 20105), 
ENC ("ISO-10646-UCS-2", 1200), 
ENC ("iso-2022-jp", 50220), 
ENC ("iso-2022-jpeuc", 51932), 
ENC ("iso-2022-kr", 50225), 
ENC ("iso-2022-kr-7", 50225), 
ENC ("iso-2022-kr-7bit", 50225), 
ENC ("iso-2022-kr-8", 51949), 
ENC ("iso-2022-kr-8bit", 51949), 
ENC ("iso-8859-1", 28591), 
ENC ("iso-8859-11", 874), 
ENC ("iso-8859-13", 28603), 
ENC ("iso-8859-15", 28605), 
ENC ("iso-8859-2", 28592), 
ENC ("iso-8859-3", 28593), 
ENC ("iso-8859-4", 28594), 
ENC ("iso-8859-5", 28595), 
ENC ("iso-8859-6", 28596), 
ENC ("iso-8859-7", 28597), 
ENC ("iso-8859-8", 28598), 
ENC ("ISO-8859-8 Visual", 28598), 
ENC ("iso-8859-8-i", 38598), 
ENC ("iso-8859-9", 28599), 
ENC ("iso-ir-100", 28591), 
ENC ("iso-ir-101", 28592), 
ENC ("iso-ir-109", 28593), 
ENC ("iso-ir-110", 28594), 
ENC ("iso-ir-126", 28597), 
ENC ("iso-ir-127", 28596), 
ENC ("iso-ir-138", 28598), 
ENC ("iso-ir-144", 28595), 
ENC ("iso-ir-148", 28599), 
ENC ("iso-ir-149", 949), 
ENC ("iso-ir-58", 936), 
ENC ("iso-ir-6", 20127), 
ENC ("ISO646-US", 20127), 
ENC ("iso8859-1", 28591), 
ENC ("iso8859-2", 28592), 
ENC ("ISO_646.irv:1991", 20127), 
ENC ("iso_8859-1", 28591), 
ENC ("ISO_8859-15", 28605), 
ENC ("iso_8859-1:1987", 28591), 
ENC ("iso_8859-2", 28592), 
ENC ("iso_8859-2:1987", 28592), 
ENC ("ISO_8859-3", 28593), 
ENC ("ISO_8859-3:1988", 28593), 
ENC ("ISO_8859-4", 28594), 
ENC ("ISO_8859-4:1988", 28594), 
ENC ("ISO_8859-5", 28595), 
ENC ("ISO_8859-5:1988", 28595), 
ENC ("ISO_8859-6", 28596), 
ENC ("ISO_8859-6:1987", 28596), 
ENC ("ISO_8859-7", 28597), 
ENC ("ISO_8859-7:1987", 28597), 
ENC ("ISO_8859-8", 28598), 
ENC ("ISO_8859-8:1988", 28598), 
ENC ("ISO_8859-9", 28599), 
ENC ("ISO_8859-9:1989", 28599), 
ENC ("Johab", 1361), 
ENC ("koi", 20866), 
ENC ("koi8", 20866), 
ENC ("koi8-r", 20866), 
ENC ("koi8-ru", 21866), 
ENC ("koi8-u", 21866), 
ENC ("koi8r", 20866), 
ENC ("korean", 949), 
ENC ("ks-c-5601", 949), 
ENC ("ks-c5601", 949), 
ENC ("KSC5601", 949), 
ENC ("KSC_5601", 949), 
ENC ("ks_c_5601", 949), 
ENC ("ks_c_5601-1987", 949), 
ENC ("ks_c_5601-1989", 949), 
ENC ("ks_c_5601_1987", 949), 
ENC ("l1", 28591), 
ENC ("l2", 28592), 
ENC ("l3", 28593), 
ENC ("l4", 28594), 
ENC ("l5", 28599), 
ENC ("l9", 28605), 
ENC ("latin1", 28591), 
ENC ("latin2", 28592), 
ENC ("latin3", 28593), 
ENC ("latin4", 28594), 
ENC ("latin5", 28599), 
ENC ("latin9", 28605), 
ENC ("logical", 28598), 
ENC ("macintosh", 10000), 
ENC ("ms_Kanji", 932), 
ENC ("Norwegian", 20108), 
ENC ("NS_4551-1", 20108), 
ENC ("PC-Multilingual-850+euro", 858), 
ENC ("SEN_850200_B", 20107), 
ENC ("shift-jis", 932), 
ENC ("shift_jis", 932), 
ENC ("sjis", 932), 
ENC ("Swedish", 20107), 
ENC ("TIS-620", 874), 
ENC ("ucs-2", 1200), 
ENC ("unicode", 1200), 
ENC ("unicode-1-1-utf-7", 65000), 
ENC ("unicode-1-1-utf-8", 65001), 
ENC ("unicode-2-0-utf-7", 65000), 
ENC ("unicode-2-0-utf-8", 65001), 
ENC ("unicodeFFFE", 1201),
ENC ("us", 20127), 
ENC ("us-ascii", 20127), 
ENC ("utf-16", 1200), 
ENC ("UTF-16BE", 1201), 
ENC ("UTF-16LE", 1200),
ENC ("utf-32", 12000),
ENC ("UTF-32BE", 12001),
ENC ("UTF-32LE", 12000),
ENC ("utf-7", 65000), 
ENC ("utf-8", 65001),
ENC ("visual", 28598), 
ENC ("windows-1250", 1250), 
ENC ("windows-1251", 1251), 
ENC ("windows-1252", 1252), 
ENC ("windows-1253", 1253), 
ENC ("Windows-1254", 1254), 
ENC ("windows-1255", 1255), 
ENC ("windows-1256", 1256), 
ENC ("windows-1257", 1257), 
ENC ("windows-1258", 1258), 
ENC ("windows-874", 874), 
ENC ("x-ansi", 1252), 
ENC ("x-Chinese-CNS", 20000), 
ENC ("x-Chinese-Eten", 20002), 
ENC ("x-cp1250", 1250), 
ENC ("x-cp1251", 1251), 
ENC ("x-cp20001", 20001), 
ENC ("x-cp20003", 20003), 
ENC ("x-cp20004", 20004), 
ENC ("x-cp20005", 20005), 
ENC ("x-cp20261", 20261), 
ENC ("x-cp20269", 20269), 
ENC ("x-cp20936", 20936), 
ENC ("x-cp20949", 20949),
ENC ("x-cp50227", 50227), 
//ENC (L"x-cp50229", 50229), 
//ENC (L"X-EBCDIC-JapaneseAndUSCanada", 50931), 
ENC ("X-EBCDIC-KoreanExtended", 20833), 
ENC ("x-euc", 51932), 
ENC ("x-euc-cn", 51936), 
ENC ("x-euc-jp", 51932), 
ENC ("x-Europa", 29001), 
ENC ("x-IA5", 20105), 
ENC ("x-IA5-German", 20106), 
ENC ("x-IA5-Norwegian", 20108), 
ENC ("x-IA5-Swedish", 20107), 
ENC ("x-iscii-as", 57006), 
ENC ("x-iscii-be", 57003), 
ENC ("x-iscii-de", 57002), 
ENC ("x-iscii-gu", 57010), 
ENC ("x-iscii-ka", 57008), 
ENC ("x-iscii-ma", 57009), 
ENC ("x-iscii-or", 57007), 
ENC ("x-iscii-pa", 57011), 
ENC ("x-iscii-ta", 57004), 
ENC ("x-iscii-te", 57005), 
ENC ("x-mac-arabic", 10004), 
ENC ("x-mac-ce", 10029), 
ENC ("x-mac-chinesesimp", 10008), 
ENC ("x-mac-chinesetrad", 10002), 
ENC ("x-mac-croatian", 10082), 
ENC ("x-mac-cyrillic", 10007), 
ENC ("x-mac-greek", 10006), 
ENC ("x-mac-hebrew", 10005), 
ENC ("x-mac-icelandic", 10079), 
ENC ("x-mac-japanese", 10001), 
ENC ("x-mac-korean", 10003), 
ENC ("x-mac-romanian", 10010), 
ENC ("x-mac-thai", 10021), 
ENC ("x-mac-turkish", 10081), 
ENC ("x-mac-ukrainian", 10017), 
ENC ("x-ms-cp932", 932),
ENC ("x-sjis", 932), 
ENC ("x-unicode-1-1-utf-7", 65000), 
ENC ("x-unicode-1-1-utf-8", 65001), 
ENC ("x-unicode-2-0-utf-7", 65000), 
ENC ("x-unicode-2-0-utf-8", 65001), 
ENC ("x-x-big5", 950),
```

Test case:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace consoleencoding
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            var tmpFile = Path.GetTempFileName ();
            TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(File.Open(tmpFile, FileMode.Create), Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));
            tw.WriteLine("éèçàôûêâ");
            tw.Close();
            Process.Start ("vi", tmpFile);
        }
    }
}
```